# How can I get the inverse of adding up all the numbers in from 1 to a given number?

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I'm not entirely sure on how to ask this question. I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do:

First, I will add up all the numbers from `1` (it will always be `1`) to a range, say `10`:

```js
let input = 10
let out = 0

while (input > 0) {
  out += input--
}

// 10 + 9 + 8 .... + 2 + 1 = 55
console.log(out)
```

What I am trying to do is to get the input number, `10`, back, from the output, `55`. i.e,

```
const out = addRange(10) // 55
inverseRange(out) // 10
```

I feel there might be a simple formula to get this, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have tried trial and error solutions, but to no avail, I feel this would be a bad solution too.

Any help, suggestions or improvements are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really a mathematics question (looking for a formula). Once you have the formula, we can help you convert it to a computer program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can simplify your `addRange` function, to [Carl Gauss' formula](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra2/Sequences/SSGauss.html), `(first+last)*(last/2)`, which can be simplified to this, since you're always working from 1:

```
(x ** 2 + x) / 2
```

You can use a heavily simplified quadratic formula, to grab the only positive value (since you will never have negative values):

```js
const addRange = x => (x ** 2 + x) / 2
const inverse = x => Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * x) / 2 - 0.5

console.log(addRange(10))
console.log(inverse(55))
```

**Explanation**:

> First, lets break down Gauss' formula. We already know that when x = 10, the output is 55, so lets write that, and try to solve for x:
>
> ```js
> (x + 1) / 2 * x = 55    
> (x + 1) / 2 = 55 / x    // divide by x
> x + 1 = 110 / x         // multiply by 2
> x = 110 / x - 1         // minus 1
> x^2 = 110 - x           // multiply by x
> x^2 + x = 110           // add x
> x^2 + x - 110 = 0       // minus 55
> ```
>
> Now we are left with a quadratic equation.
>   We can use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to find x:
>
> [image: formula]
>
> First, lets write that into JS:
>
> ```js
> (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
> ```
>
> We can substitute out `a` and `b` for 1, these will never change in our equation, and since it is negative 30, we can invert the minus before `4ac`:
>
> ```js
> (-1 * 1 + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(1, 2) + (4 * 1 * c))) / (2 * 1)
> ```
>
> which simplifies to
>
> ```js
> (-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + (4 * c))) / 2
> // or
> Math.sqrt(1 + (4 * c)) / 2 - 0.5
> ```
>
> Note however, in our equation, our 55 was doubled to 110, so we should do the same inside our formula (`4 -> 8`):
>
> ```js
> Math.sqrt(1 + (8 * c)) / 2 - 0.5
> ```

Comment: thanks, can you explain how it works? it seems very random

Comment: @Nuggets: even without math (like your solution for `addRange`), this can be done by the very same way: `const inverseRange = x => { let c = 0, steps = 0; while((c += ++steps) < x); return steps; };`, though the above described method is obviously better. Please read the links provided, understanding how to solve `addRange` properly is critical for understanding the above solution.

Comment: @Nuggets Added an explanation now :)

Comment: @RaymondChen Whoops, you're right, Ill edit those now :)

Comment: I would complete the square instead of using the quadratic formula: x^2  + x = 2N => x^2 + x + 1/4 = 2N+1/4 => (x+1/2)^2 = 2N+1/4 => x+1/2 = sqrt(2N+1/4) => x = sqrt(2N+1/4) - 1/2

Comment: Sure, if it were a normal question, I would do the same, but I'm not sure how I would do that in code, so I just stuck with the formula, which simplified pretty well. @RaymondChen

Comment: @RaymondChen Isn't that just my formula simplified a tad more? Nonetheless, it works :)

Comment: It's the same thing, but completing the square looks less like magic. You didn't have to know some secret formula.